# How to access system properties from a Tomcat app deployed on Cloudbees?

Tags: cloudbees

I want to run a Tomcat app in Cloudbees. This app accesses some private and confidential properties from the file system. How could I access a file system on Cloudbees? Please note that it should be highly protected, e.g. 700 or similar.

Regards,
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RUN@Cloud platform don't provide a persistent (nor distributed) filesystem. So you can't use it to as canonical store for those files, but need to use an external file store to match your security requirements, and copy them as application is starting (or lazy-load) to java.io.temp directory. As files are stored on RUN@Cloud there is no security issue as your server instance is fully isolated, and files will be deleted after application undeployed/passivated

So you can use Amazon S3 or comparable to store files

Another option is for you to attach properties to the RUN@Cloud instance as configuration parameters, and access them as System properties. See http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Configuration+Parameters

Answer (score 0):

If they data is modest in size - you could consider using properties - using the CLI you can set them using

```
bees config:set propertyName=value
```

you can then access that as a System property (for example) in your application. The properties themselves are stored encrypted by cloudbees.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually moved to OpenShift since then and I solved the problem. Thank you for your answers